# Oracle: Creating Move Order API not working

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm creating a Move Order by API but the problem I’m getting is it's not processing the Line Items as a bash, it's doing each individually. I tried removing the Header from within the loop but the result persists. Thanks for your in advance.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE XXGSC_CREATE_MO
as
x_return_status VARCHAR2 (1);  
x_msg_data      VARCHAR2 (4000);  
x_msg_count     NUMBER;  
l_user_id       NUMBER;  
l_resp_id       NUMBER;  
l_appl_id       NUMBER;  
l_hdr_rec inv_move_order_pub.trohdr_rec_type :=      inv_move_order_pub.g_miss_trohdr_rec;  
x_hdr_rec inv_move_order_pub.trohdr_rec_type := inv_move_order_pub.g_miss_trohdr_rec;  
l_line_tbl inv_move_order_pub.trolin_tbl_type:= inv_move_order_pub.g_miss_trolin_tbl;  
x_line_tbl inv_move_order_pub.trolin_tbl_type:=  inv_move_order_pub.g_miss_trolin_tbl;  
x_hdr_val_rec inv_move_order_pub.trohdr_val_rec_type;  
x_line_val_tbl inv_move_order_pub.trolin_val_tbl_type;  
v_msg_index_out NUMBER;  
l_cnt number     := 0;
l_rsr_type inv_reservation_global.mtl_reservation_tbl_type;  
l_code_combination_id gl_code_combinations.code_combination_id%type;  

CURSOR c_itm_onhand  
IS  
select msi.inventory_item_id, msi.organization_id, sum     (mmt.transaction_quantity) as qty, mmt.subinventory_code, transaction_uom,  '1203' as ccid
from mtl_material_transactions mmt
join mtl_system_items_b msi
on mmt.organization_id = msi.organization_id and mmt.inventory_item_id =  msi.inventory_item_id
where segment1 like  '1010027%'
and msi.organization_id = 102
group by msi.inventory_item_id, msi.organization_id, mmt.subinventory_code,   transaction_uom, '1203';

BEGIN  
SELECT user_id INTO l_user_id FROM fnd_user WHERE user_name = 'CONCSYS';  

SELECT fr.responsibility_id,  
fr.application_id  
INTO l_resp_id,  
l_appl_id  
FROM fnd_responsibility fr,  
fnd_responsibility_tl frt  
WHERE fr.responsibility_id  = frt.responsibility_id  
AND frt.responsibility_name = 'ISD-Inventory Super User'; --Responsibility  
fnd_global.apps_initialize (l_user_id, l_resp_id, l_appl_id);  

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Creating MO');

FOR i IN c_itm_onhand  
LOOP  
l_cnt :=  l_cnt + 1;
mo_global.set_policy_context ('S', i.organization_id);  
inv_globals.set_org_id (i.organization_id);  
mo_global.init ('INV');  
--SELECT code_combination_id  
--INTO l_code_combination_id  
--FROM gl_code_combinations_kfv  
--WHERE concatenated_segments = '01-520-5250-0000-000';  
l_line_tbl.DELETE;  
x_line_tbl.DELETE;  
--Header
l_hdr_rec.date_required               := SYSDATE;  
l_hdr_rec.header_status               := inv_globals.g_to_status_preapproved;  
l_hdr_rec.organization_id             := 102;  
l_hdr_rec.status_date                 := SYSDATE;  
l_hdr_rec.transaction_type_id         := inv_globals.g_type_transfer_order_issue; --Type:Move Order Issue  
l_hdr_rec.move_order_type             := inv_globals.g_move_order_requisition;  
l_hdr_rec.db_flag                     := fnd_api.g_true;  
l_hdr_rec.operation                   := inv_globals.g_opr_create;  
l_hdr_rec.description                 := 'Test MO5';  
--l_hdr_rec.to_account_id               := i.ccid;  
--l_hdr_rec.from_subinventory_code      := i.subinventory_code;  

--Table Lines
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).date_required          := SYSDATE;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).inventory_item_id      := i.inventory_item_id;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).line_id                := fnd_api.g_miss_num;  
--l_line_tbl (l_cnt).line_number            := l_cnt;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).line_status            := inv_globals.g_to_status_preapproved;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).transaction_type_id    := inv_globals.g_type_transfer_order_issue;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).organization_id        := i.organization_id;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).quantity               := i.qty;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).status_date            := SYSDATE;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).uom_code               := i.transaction_uom;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).db_flag                := fnd_api.g_true;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).operation              := inv_globals.g_opr_create;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).from_subinventory_code := i.subinventory_code;  
l_line_tbl (l_cnt).to_account_id          := i.ccid;  
--l_line_tbl (l_cnt).lot_number             := i.lot_number;  
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('===================================');  
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Calling INV_MOVE_ORDER_PUB to Create MO');  
INV_MOVE_ORDER_PUB.PROCESS_MOVE_ORDER (p_api_version_number => 1.0, p_init_msg_list => fnd_api.g_false, p_return_values => fnd_api.g_false, p_commit => fnd_api.g_false, x_return_status => x_return_status, x_msg_count => x_msg_count, x_msg_data => x_msg_data, p_trohdr_rec => l_hdr_rec, p_trolin_tbl => l_line_tbl, x_trohdr_rec => x_hdr_rec, x_trohdr_val_rec => x_hdr_val_rec, x_trolin_tbl => x_line_tbl, x_trolin_val_tbl => x_line_val_tbl);  
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (x_return_status);  
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (x_msg_count);  
IF x_return_status = 'S' THEN  
  COMMIT;  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Move Order Successfully Created');  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Move Order Number is :=> '||x_hdr_rec.request_number);  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('===================================');  
ELSE  
  ROLLBACK;  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Move Order Creation Failed Due to Following Reasons');  
 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('===================================');  
END IF;  
IF x_msg_count > 0 THEN  
  FOR v_index IN 1 .. x_msg_count  
  LOOP  
   fnd_msg_pub.get (p_msg_index => v_index, p_encoded => 'F', p_data => x_msg_data, p_msg_index_out => v_msg_index_out );  
    x_msg_data := SUBSTR (x_msg_data, 1, 200);  
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (x_msg_data);  
  END LOOP;  
END IF;  
END LOOP;  
END XXGSC_CREATE_MO;
```

Comment: That's the way you've written it: for each loop, you put one record into `l_line_tbl` and pass it to `INV_MOVE_ORDER_PUB`.  Instead, move the `l_line_tbl.DELETE` to before the start of your loop.  In the loop, increment `l_cnt` and add the line to `l_line_tbl`.  Then, after the loop, call `INV_MOVE_ORDER_PUB` only one time.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Thanks for your help, it works!

Comment: I'll write my comment up as an answer.  Please accept it so that your question comes off the "unanswered questions" queue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's not processing the Line Items as a bash, it's doing each individually

That's the way you've written it: for each loop, you put one record into l_line_tbl and pass it to INV_MOVE_ORDER_PUB.

Instead, move the l_line_tbl.DELETE to before the start of your loop. In the loop, increment l_cnt and add the line to l_line_tbl. Then, after the loop, call INV_MOVE_ORDER_PUB only one time.